# textpad 8 regular expression with multiple conditions

Tags: regex, textpad

I've searched through all of the TextPad regex postings on superuser.com and have not found an answer to my query.  It is -- how can I provide two conditions in a TextPad 8 file search regular expression?  In particular, I want to find all lines in all files that contain the strings Error or Warning, which I can do using the regex `error|warning`, but in addition to that, I want to select only the subset of those lines where another specified text string, e.g. `expir`, is not present anywhere on the lines, before or after the location of the matching string from the first regex.

I've tried various forms of putting a conjunction like `&` or `&&` between the two regexes, but cannot find a syntax that works.  Do TextPad regular expressions include support for lookahead and lookbehind zero-width assertions?  In perl, I could say

```
    (?<!expir).*?error|warning(?!.*?expir)
```

.  I entered that in TextPad, and it caused no errors, but it also did not work.  It selected all of the lines that contained either `error` or `warning` but did not exclude lines that also contained `expir`.

Comment: To test if something is NOT present, you have to use this construction: `((?!expir).)*` so your regex becomes: `^((?!expir).)*(?:error|warning)((?!expir).)*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will find what you want:

```
^(?=(?:(?!expir).)*$).*(?:error|warning)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                       : begining of line
    (?=                 : start lookahead
        (?:             : start non capture group
            (?!expir)   : negative lookahead, make sure w don'thave expir
                            You may want to add wordboundaries if you don't want to match "expiration"
                            (?!\bexpir\b)
            .           : any character but newline
        )*              : group may appear 0 or moe times
        $               : end of line
    )                   : end of lookahead
                            at this point we are sure we don't have "expir" in the line
                            so, go to match the wanted words
    .*                  : 0 or more any character but newline
    (?:                 : start non capture group
        error           : literally error, you could do "\berror\b" if you don't want to match "errors"
        |               : OR
        warning         : literally warning, you could do "\bwarning\b" if you don't want to match "warnings"
    )
```

With file like:

```
error
warning
abc expir 
abc expir warning
abc error expir def
```

it matches lines 1 and 2 only.